# Convert vector of vector to pointer of pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, stdvector

Assume I have a C library API function which takes pointer of pointers as parameter. However since I am programming in C++ I would like to take advantage of std vector to deal with the dynamic memory. How can I efficiently convert vector of vector into pointer of pointer? Right now I am using this.

```
#include <vector>

/* C like api */
void foo(short **psPtr, const int x, const int y);    

int main()
{
    const int x = 2, y = 3;
    std::vector<std::vector<short>> vvsVec(x, std::vector<short>(y, 0));
    short **psPtr = new short*[x];

    /* point psPtr to the vector */
    int c = 0;
    for (auto &vsVec : vvsVec)
        psPtr[c++] = &vsVec[0];

    /* api call */
    foo(psPtr, x, y);        

    delete[] psPtr;
    return 0;
}
```

Is this the best way to achieve the goal? Can I get rid of the "new delete" thing by using iterator or some std method in this case? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
According to answers I am now using this version to interface with C code. I am posting it here.

```
#include <vector>

/* C like api */
void foo(short **psPtr, const int x, const int y);    

int main()
{
    const int x = 2, y = 3;
    std::vector<std::vector<short>> vvsVec(x, std::vector<short>(y, 0));
    std::vector<short*> vpsPtr(x, nullptr);

    /* point vpsPtr to the vector */
    int c = 0;
    for (auto &vsVec : vvsVec)
        vpsPtr[c++] = vsVec.data();

    /* api call */
    foo(vpsPtr.data(), x, y);        

    return 0;
}
```

Looks more C++ like to me. Thanks for all!

Comment: Drop one level of vector and take the address of a pointer to the first element of that flat vector.

Comment: Only making it looks nicer, you can replace psPtr with a vector<short *>, and set it up with some function in algorithm.

Comment: The API function either needs a size parameter or has the convention that a null pointer denotes the last element, in which case you must add a `nullptr` at the end.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Thanks I will update it. I am not so familiar with C convention. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @yc2986: Well, I thought you were talking about a real function :) But in any case, the function must have some way to know the size (or the sizes). What should it do if it just receives a single pointer *and* there is no convention to represent the last element(s)? How could you ever hope to implement such a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this the best way to achieve the goal?

If you are sure that the vector of vectors will outlive `psPtr`, then yes. Otherwise, you run the risk that `psPtr` will contain invalid pointers.

> Can I get rid of the "new delete" thing by using iterator or some std method in this case?

Yes. I suggest using:

```
std::vector<short*> psPtr(vvsVec.size());
```

and then use `&psPtr[0]` in the call to the C API function. That removes the burden of memory management from your code.

```
foo(&psPtr[0]);
```

Comment: This looks pretty neat. Never thought of vector of pointer before. Thanks!

Comment: @yc2986: A vector of pointers is usually an anti-pattern. If you never thought of doing this, this is actually a good thing.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the info. I think for everything C++ project I will never do this. But for interfacing with C code it may have some value. I will never do thing like generating a vector of pointer then point each of them to "new" allocated objects and manually delete them.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::vector<short*> vecOfPtrs;
for (auto&& vec : vvsVec)
    vecOfPtrs.push_back(&vec[0]);

foo(&vecOfPtrs[0]);
```

Comment: Since you know the size of the container `vecOfPtrs` ahead of time, you should really initialize it to that size. This prevents potential memory relocations, and potential exceptions due to resizing.

Comment: Why `&vec[0]` and not `vec.data()`?  I can think of at least 3 reasons to use `vec.data()` over `&vec[0]`, and zero to use `&vec[0]` over `vec.data()`.  (empty vectors, `vector<bool>`, `std::addressof` issues, in decreasing importance)

Comment: @Yakk I guess old habits die hard from C++03. `vec.data()` is superior. However, your first reason isn't good at all since `vec.data()` should return `&vec[0]`, even for an empty vector, and the C++ standard allows taking the address of one-past-the-end of an array.

Comment: @rlbond you cannot call `v[v.size()]` -- it is equivalent to `*(v.begin()+v.size())`, which is `*v.end()`, even if you immediately `&` it; dereferencing an `end` iterator is illegal in `vector`.  Niw this may be unlikely to format your drive, but it generating run time debug messages seems likeky.