# Convert vector of vector of bools to pointer of pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, raw-pointer

I have a problem similar to the one mentioned in the question [Convert vector of vector to pointer of pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400272/convert-vector-of-vector-to-pointer-of-pointer).

The only difference is that I have to use booleans instead of shorts.

But if I compile this code:

```
#include <vector>

/* C like api */
void foo(bool **psPtr, const int x, const int y);

int main()
{
  const int x = 2, y = 3;
  std::vector<std::vector<bool>> vvsVec(x, std::vector<bool>(y, 0));
  std::vector<bool *> vpsPtr(x, nullptr);

  /* point vpsPtr to the vector */
  int c = 0;
  for (auto &vsVec : vvsVec)
    vpsPtr[c++] = vsVec.data();

  /* api call */
  foo(vpsPtr.data(), x, y);

  return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

> ./dummy/main.cpp:15: error: assigning to
> '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<bool *> >::value_type' (aka
> 'bool *') from incompatible type 'void'

and

> ./dummy/main.cpp:15: error: void value not ignored as
> it ought to be
> vpsPtr[c++] = vsVec.data();

Please, can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: This might explain it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568986/what-happens-when-you-call-data-on-a-stdvectorbool

Comment: A common solution to this dilemma is to represent a vector of booleans as a `std::vector<char>`. If strong typing is desired, `enum class fake_bool : char { fake_false, fake_true };` or something similar can be used. For more convenience you can implement conversion operators to/from `bool`.

Comment: @KondradRudolph I was thinking about the usual replacements, but when the aim is to get a `bool**` I am not sure if any of them is applicable

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<bool>` is a specialization of `std::vector` that does not behave like other `std::vector`s do. It does not necessarily store the elements contiguously. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool):

> `std::vector<bool>` behaves similarly to `std::vector`, but in order to be
> space efficient, it:
>
> - Does not necessarily store its elements as a contiguous array.
> - Exposes class `std::vector<bool>::reference` as a method of accessing individual bits. In particular, objects of this class are returned by
>   `operator[]` by value.
> - Does not use `std::allocator_traits::construct` to construct bit values.
> - Does not guarantee that different elements in the same container can be modified concurrently by different threads.

The savings in space come at a relatively high price. For example, you cannot use `data()` to get a pointer to a contiguous array of `bool`s. If you want such an array you need to set it up yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `std::vector<bool>` is a specialization of the generic `std::vector` template, and it stores `bool` values in a space-efficient way unlike any other data-types (it stores one bit per `bool` value). That means `std::vector<bool>` can't be used in all the same contexts as any other vector.

You need to create your own dynamically allocated arrays to handle it:

```
std::vector<bool*> vpsPtr(vvsVec.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < vvsVec.size(); ++i)
{
    vpsPtr[i] = new bool[vvsVec[i].size()];
    // TODO: Copy each and every vector element vvsVec[i][j] into vpsPtr[i][j]
}
```

Don't forget to `delete[]` the memory when you're finished with it.

Comment: @FedericoNardi Maybe this is what you need: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/example/example1.cpp

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin dynamic_bitset does not have data() member function.